# regarding extracting the first digit of each cell value for a given column

Tags: windows, excel, csv, ms-office

In the Excel file, there is a column consisting of numerical values, such as

```
column1
12.1
23.2
12.5
34.6
```

I need to generate a new column, which only include the first digit of each cell value in the above column. Thus, the result looks like as follows

```
column1   column2
12.1      1
23.2      2
12.5      1
34.6      3
```

How to do that in Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In B1 enter:

**=--LEFT(A1,1)**  and copy down as far as needed.